# Query over grouping result

Tags: solr

For example, We have the follow documents in Solr:

```
itemA
 -name: apple
 -cate: fruit
 -createdate: 2023-02-28T00:24:00Z
 -color: red

itemB
 -name: pear
 -cate: fruit
 -createdate: 2023-01-20T00:24:00Z
 -color: yellow

itemC
 -name: potato
 -cate: vegitable
 -createdate: 2023-02-20T00:24:00Z
 -color: yellow
```

We have used the Solr query to group the docs with field "cate" and order by "createdDate" Desc, then limit the group item to 1, so it returns the latest item of each type. The solr query is like

```
?q=*%3A*&start=0&rows=10&facet=true&facet.field=color&group=true&group.field=cate&group.limit=1&group.sort=createddate desc&group.ngroups=true&group.truncate=true&group.facet=true&group.format=grouped
```

The returned result is like below

```
itemA
 -name: apple
 -cate: fruit
 -createdate: 2023-02-28T00:24:00Z
 -color: red

itemC
 -name: potato
 -cate: vegitable
 -createdate: 2023-02-20T00:24:00Z
 -color: yellow

facets:
   color: 
     red: 1
     yellow: 1
```

Now, we want to apply the facet query, for example, user clicked on the "red" on the facets filter in the UI. So the result will still be latest item for each "cate", and based on that, apply "color: red". We have tried facet.query or group query, since we need to always get the "latest" item, we can not use those.

Does anyone has this situation before (apply query on a grouping results)? Pleaes kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: If the goal to only return `itemA` in your example, or return the latest potato with the color red in addition to the fruit?

Comment: @MatsLindh, the goal is to be able to apply the facet filter on the grouped results. So for this scenario, if facet filter red is applied, it only returns "itemA" as the grouping results. And if facet filter yellow is applied, only returns "ItemC" as the grouping results.